# Creating a Panel of Button GUI

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a board for a game, i first made a frame then if the user //enters the rows and columns as numbers and pushes the start button, it should remove all //whats on frame and add a panel with a grid layout having buttons everywhere

Here is the code ( Problem is the frame gets cleared and nothing appears)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    JButton newButton;
    JButton Start;
    JTextArea row;
    JTextArea col;
    JLabel background;
    JLabel rows;
    JLabel columns;
    JLabel Error;
    JPanel myPanel;
    JCheckBox box;


    public Frame()
    {
                //adding frame


                setTitle("DVONN Game");
            setSize(1000, 700);
            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLayout(null);
        //making start button
        Start = new JButton(new ImageIcon("Start"));
        Start.setBounds(500, 30, 300, 300);
        Start.setOpaque(true);
        Start.addActionListener(this);

            //make background
        background = new JLabel();
        background.setBounds(0, -300, 2000, 1500);
        background.setIcon(Color.BLUE));

        rows = new JLabel("Enter the rows");
        columns = new JLabel("Enter the columns");
        rows.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        columns.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        rows.setBounds(10,10,100,30);
        columns.setBounds(10,45,105,30);

        row = new JTextArea();
        col = new JTextArea();
        row.setBounds(120,10,100,30);
        col.setBounds(120,45,100,30);

        Error = new JLabel("Enter numbers plz!");
                Error.setBounds(10, 100, 400, 30);
        Error.setForeground(Color.RED);
        Error.setVisible(true);

        box = new JCheckBox("Enable Random Filling");
        box.setBounds(10, 200, 150, 20);
        box.setVisible(true);

        myPanel = new JPanel();
        myPanel.setBounds(30, 30, 700, 500);
        myPanel.setVisible(true);

        newButton = new JButton();
        newButton.setOpaque(true);

        getContentPane().add(box);
        getContentPane().add(rows);
        getContentPane().add(columns);
        getContentPane().add(row);
        getContentPane().add(col);
        getContentPane().add(Start);
        getContentPane().add(background);

        this.validate();
        this.repaint();

    }


    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new Frame();
    }

      //adding actions for start button


      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        boolean flag = true;
        String r1 = row.getText();
        String c1 = col.getText();
        int x = 0,y = 0;

        try{
            x = Integer.parseInt(r1);
            y = Integer.parseInt(c1);
        } catch(NumberFormatException l) {
            flag = false;
        }

        int size = x * y;

        if (flag == true) {
            this.getContentPane().removeAll();
            this.validate();
            this.repaint();

            myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(x, y));

            while(size != 0)
            {
                myPanel.add(newButton);
                size --;
            }

            this.getContentPane().add(myPanel);

        } else {

            this.getContentPane().add(Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sry plz change 
Start = new JButton(new ImageIcon("Start"));
into
Start = new JButton("Start");

and change 
background.setIcon(Color.BLUE));
into 
background.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with this code

1. Is it really needed to post that much code. A simple UI with one button to press, and then another component which should appear would be sufficient for an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)
2. The use of `null` layout's. Please learn to use `LayoutManager`s
3. Each Swing component can only be contained once in the hierarchy. So this loop is useless since you add the same component over and over again (not to mention that a negative size would result in an endless loop)

```
while(size != 0){
  myPanel.add(newButton);
  size --;
}
```

Have you tried debugging to see whether `size` is actually `>0`. Since you silently ignore `ParseException`s you might end up with a `size` of `0` which will clean the content pane and add nothing

Then do as goldilocks suggests and call `validate` after adding the components. See the javadoc of the `Container#add` method

> This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy. If the container has already been displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to display the added component.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions,  as for ur 3rd remark, i wanted to add the same button for the whole grid(panel) how do u suggest i could do this ?

Comment: @OmarKhaled You can't. You will have to create multiple buttons. Note you can share the action (or actionlistener) behind those buttons though

Comment: hmm can I create the new button in the loop and add it to the panel ?

Answer (score 1):

Call `validate()` and `repaint()` *after* the new elements have been added instead of after the old ones have been removed.

You don't need to be calling `setVisible()` on individual components, call it after `pack()` on the Frame itself, and you shouldn't use `validate()` and `repaint()` in the constructor.  Ie, replace those with:

```
pack();
setVisible(true);
```

or you can do that on the object after the constructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
   public static void main(String[]args)
{
    new Frame();
}
```

by

```
   public static void main(String[]args)
{
    new Frame().setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: obviously the frame is already visible if the OP is having a problem with a button action.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the call to `this.setVisible` in the constructor and make this your main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    final Frame fr = new Frame();

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             fr.setVisible(true);
         }
    });
}
```

This will make sure that the frame elements will be in place before it becomes visible.

Comment: this won't cause the OP's problem tho ;)

Comment: @goldilocks Sorry I didn't see that he was missing the `pack()` method.